# arbitrary input from stdin to shell

Tags: security, shell, unix

So I have this existing command that accepts a single argument, but I need something that accepts the argument over stdin instead.

A shell script wrapper like the following works, but as I will be allowing untrusted users to pass arbitrary strings on stdin, I'm wondering if there's potential for someone to execute arbitary commands on the shell.

```
#!/bin/sh
$CMD "`cat`"
```

Obviously if $CMD has a vulnerability in the way it processes the argument there's nothing I can do, so I'm concerned stuff like this:

- Somehow allow the user to escape the double quotes and pass input into argument #2 of $CMD
- Somehow cause another arbitary command to run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter looks fine to me, but the command might be a bit shaky, if it can have a space in it. Also, if you're looking to get just one line from the user then you might prefer this:

```
#!/bin/bash

read line
exec "$CMD" "$line"
```

Comment: yeah good point about $CMD, although I just used it for illustration purposes (it will be a literal in my production code). 

There may be multiple lines in the data so I can't do a read like that.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of code would be broken if `"$(cmd)"` could expand to multiple words.

Comment: The part I was concerned about was
    "`cat`"
the $CMD is irrelevant (hm

Comment: I did mean the `cat`, I just generalised the answer. Changed the backticks to $(), so it could be in a proper code tag. As you have now seen the problem yourself. :)